# How to implement a scrollable text view with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

## Backgroud:

I'm new to jetpack compose family, I've followed some tutorial on `developer.android.com` and know the basics about viewModel and uiState etc.

## What I want:

A simple application like:

```
---------------------
| button1 | button2 |
---------------------
| log1...           |
| log2...           |
| log3...           |
---------------------
```

When i press either a button, it will execute some task (either sync/async) and set the result to a StateFlow, thus the UI would update.

## Question:

1. How should I implement the `log` view there, like which built-in composable i should use? And I expect the view can be scrolled up and down.
2. Will there be like memory issues if the view holds too much text inside?

Comment: Have you looked into LazyColumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [`verticalScroll`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).verticalScroll(androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollState,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean)) Modifier like this:

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
    text = loggingText,
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
)
```

There previously was an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/312294386) causing crashes on long texts, so make sure that you use the latest Compose dependencies for this approach:

> The following release(s) address this bug. It is possible this bug has only been partially addressed: 
> androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.0-beta03
> androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-android:1.6.0-beta03

However, if you plan to use a huge number of lines, safer approach is to use a [`LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyColumn(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)). It will lazily compose the child items, so you can use one Text Composable for each line:

```
var logLines: List<String> = remember { 
    mutableStateListOf("Log 1", "Log 2", "Log 3", "Log 4")
}

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
) {
    items(logLines) { logLine ->
        Text(text = logLine)
    }
}
```

You then can add new lines by just calling

```
logLines.add("Log 5")
```

Comment: It should work, I'll take a deeper read into the docs. :D